# Adding 2 masks with (math Add) node gives strange result

Tags: node-editor

I can't find a way to explain this problem. I'm trying to add two masks with the math node in the material editor. The picture should explain very well. As you can see the addition of the two masks makes a completely unreasonable result. I appreciate any help I can get.

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSO7p.jpg

Comment: Are you able to upload a packed blend file? There's not enough info to go on here.

Comment: I’d guess that the first mask output is producing a *negative* result - which is why it’s not visible in the first render but is subtracting from the combined result. Not enough information to give a more detailed answer.

Comment: Did you check the result in rendered mode? Sometimes the material view is a bit off, depending on the complexity of your nodetree.

Comment: @OroNZ http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=49227 Thanks for all help, I would really appreciate it if anyone look through the file. Feel free to take the textures and use it for whatever you want, it's made by me.

Comment: @RichSedman That's a great idea, I tried multiplying first mask with -1, but it didn't help.

Comment: @yann It's the same in rendered mode, but thanks.